# CvInvoke does not contain a definition of cvSetZero

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I built and referred to `Emgu.CV.World.dll` in my project. When I was trying to call the method like

```
IntPtr complexImage = CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(image.Width * image.Height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 2);
CvInvoke.cvSetZero(complexImage);
```

Visual studio complains that it could not find the definitions for both `Emgu.CV.CvEnum.IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_32F` and `cvSetZero()`. Am I still missing anything in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have VS see the enums etc, you need to add `using Emgu.CV.Enum;`to your source file. If you are using the 3.1 version of Emgu.CV the method `CvInvoke.cvSetZero()`no longer exists. It is in the 2.4.10 version, though.

Doug